# how can i add a newline or breakline on css

Tags: css

my code is in [codepen](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/XWZqGgX) how can i add breakline / new line between title and table ?

```
  <li class="slide">
      
    <H1>TITLE</H1> 
     <br />
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <td>qdf</td>
             <td>qdf</td>
          </tr>
        </table>     
      </li>
```

and css:

```
.slide {  
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: By not giving display as flex

Comment: but when i remove flex the display is not in the middle anymore

Comment: You can also try giving flex-direction as column

Comment: Try setting `flex-direction: column` in your `.slide` rule.

Answer (score 0):

The default `flex direction` is `row`. Either you can remove the flex layout or make the `flex-direction: column`.

However, `br` is not the correct way to adjust spaces between flex items. Use properties like `justify-content`, `gap`, `row-gap`, `column-gap`

```css
.slide {  
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:  column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<li class="slide">
      
    <H1>TITLE</H1> 
     <br />
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <td>qdf</td>
             <td>qdf</td>
          </tr>
        </table>     
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <section class="slider-wrapper">
  <button class="slide-arrow" id="slide-arrow-prev">
    &#8249;
  </button>
  <button class="slide-arrow" id="slide-arrow-next">
    &#8250;
  </button>
  <ul class="slides-container" id="slides-container">
    <li class="slide">
      <h1 class="title">TiTLE</h1> 
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <td>qdf</td>
             <td>qdf</td>
          </tr>
        </table> </li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<footer>
  Pen by <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Jemima Abu</a> <span class="heart">&hearts;</span>
</footer>
```

and use this css:

```
.slide {
/*   width: 100%; */
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```